# Adding messages to a div dynamically

Tags: jquery

I am adding messages dynamically using jquery, the only problem is I want to remove the same amount of messages from the bottom as the amount of messages added on top, the code I currently use is:

```
$(html).hide().prependTo("#current center").fadeIn("slow");
```

Currently I need to check the amount of divs with a `table.msgtable` within inside html to get `A`.
Then check the amount of div messages inside `#current center` to get `B`.

Then `$(".info #current>center>div").slice(B-A)` apparently. Is this an efficient way to solve this problem? I am having trouble with getting `A`.

Comment: so the problem is getting A?  why don't you just use the jquery selector and check length like so $('.the-selector-for-A).length

Comment: I need to check for it in html

Comment: huh?  no idea what you're trying to accomplish.  Can you add the markup to your question so maybe we can interpolate what you're doing?

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
$("#current>center>div:gt(5)").remove();
```

Replace 5 with one less than the maximum number of messages you want.

Also, a <center> tag? Eew!

Comment: `Also, a <center> tag? Eew!` +1 for making me laugh